# Sklearn APIs for OOP

Tags: python, oop, feature-selection

My idea is to learn how to use sklearn APIs in their full potential. I want to start with Feature Selections modules. My idea is to be able to combine several methods from sklearn and also to add Boruta later:

```
import inspect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.feature_selection as skfs

from sklearn.utils import all_estimators
from typing import Any, Dict

class FeatureSelection:

    def __init__(self, method_name: str, method_params: Dict[str, Any]):

        self.method_name = method_name
        self.method_params = method_params
        self.method = None
        "..."

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **kwargs):

        if self.method_name in list(inspect.getmembers()):
            self.method = inspect.getmembers()[self.method_name]
        else:
            raise Exception("Method not available yet.")

        self.method.fit(X, y, **kwargs)
    def transform(self, X):
        return self.method.transform(X=X)


class SklearnFeatureSelection(FeatureSelection):

    def __init__(self, method_name, method_params=Dict[str, Any]):

        super().__init__(method_name=method_name, method_params=method_params)
        
        self._check_sklearn_methods()
        self._init_sklearn_method_object()

    def _check_sklearn_methods(self):
        estimators = all_estimators(type_filter=None)
        if self.method_name not in estimators:
            raise ValueError("Method is not implemented.")

    # Instantiate the sklearn object:

    def _init_sklearn_method_object(self):
        self.method = getattr(skfs, self.method_name)(**self.method_params)

    def fit(self, X, y=None):

        self.method.fit(X, y)
        
    def transform(self, X):
        
        if self.method is None:
            raise Exception("Method not fitted yet.")
        
        return self.method.transform(X)


class StatsmodelsFeatureSelection(FeatureSelection):
    pass


class MyFsMehthod(FeatureSelection):
    pass
        
        
sklearn_fs = SklearnFeatureSelection(method_name="VarianceThreshold")
train_data = [[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]]
sklearn_fs.fit(X=train_data)
sklearn_fs.transform(X=new_data)
```

With my code I am not able to extract the sklearn libraries, does anyone know a refence or example  or correction to my code where I can see how to call all the methods from sklean and use them by name?

Currently, I have the following error, but I am not able to solve it.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 70>()
     66     pass
     68 # Example call:
---> 70 sklearn_fs = SklearnFeatureSelection(method_name="VarianceThreshold")
     71 sklearn_fs.fit(X=train_data)
     72 sklearn_fs.transform(X=new_data)

Input In [22], in SklearnFeatureSelection.__init__(self, method_name, method_params)
     32 def __init__(self, method_name, method_params=Dict[str, Any]):
     34     super().__init__(method_name=method_name, method_params=method_params)
---> 36     self._check_sklearn_methods()
     37     self._init_sklearn_method_object()

Input In [22], in SklearnFeatureSelection._check_sklearn_methods(self)
     40 estimators = all_estimators(type_filter=None)
     41 if self.method_name not in estimators:
---> 42     raise ValueError("Method is not implemented.")

ValueError: Method is not implemented.
```

Comment: Your question really isn't clear at all. What does " I am not able to extract the sklearn libraries" mean *exactly*?

Comment: Are you asking for the `sklearn` documentation?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried my best looking at the documentation, but I still have an error, I think the main problem is in the '_check_sklearn_methods' - in this function I am trying to get the methods that belong to feature selection in sklean, I selected 'type_filter=None', so in this case I get all of the 4 estimators, but when I call this method I just get the ValueError. I checked the documentation, but I am still not sure how is it possible to fix the issue.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - I tried my best checking the documentation, but I am still not sure how I can extract all the methods for feature selection.

Comment: Please provide, in the question itself, a [mcve] with the complete error message, including the stack trace. You **really must do this for questions seeking debugging help**. It still isn't clear what the problem is, but at least now you are talking about a specific error

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thank you for the comment, I added the message error, in this case I have error(s) in my methods, but I am not able to call the classes correctly.